# Formatting pandas items into a list

Tags: pandas

The following code works but when I add formats to the .format() I get an error...

```
test=['Interval: {} - {}<br>Best: {}<br>{}: {}'.format(
(pd.to_datetime(best_interval_df.loc[i].time_interval)) - timedelta(seconds=i),
(pd.to_datetime(best_interval_df.loc[i].time_interval)),
pd.to_datetime(best_interval_df.loc[i].datetime), 'Power',best_interval_df.loc[i]['best_power']) for i in best_interval_df.index]
```

['Interval: 1970-01-01 00:46:12 - 1970-01-01 00:46:13
Best: 2018-05-15 16:44:33
Power: 581.0', 'Interval: 1970-01-01 00:44:01 - 1970-01-01 00:44:03
Best: 2018-02-16 18:08:03
Power: 560.0']

```
test=['Interval: {:%H:%M:%S} - {:%H:%M:%S}<br>Best: {:%Y-%m-%d}<br>{}: {:.0f}'.format(
(pd.to_datetime(best_interval_df.loc[i].time_interval)) - timedelta(seconds=i),
(pd.to_datetime(best_interval_df.loc[i].time_interval)),
pd.to_datetime(best_interval_df.loc[i].datetime), 'Power',best_interval_df.loc[i]['best_power']) for i in best_interval_df.index]
```

Gives this error:
pd.to_datetime(best_interval_df.loc[i].datetime), 'Power',best_interval_df.loc[i]['best_power']) for i in best_interval_df.index]
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.**format**

Comment: Try `best_interval_df['best_power'].str.format("0f")`. Do you get a similar error? What dtype is the `best_power` col?

Comment: Its float64. When I try the .str.format I get the following error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas